# using $match in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a variable in my Node function.

```
var storeId;
```

The value of `storeId` may or may not be  `undefined`.

Now, if it is `undefined`, I do not want `$match` to filter out based on this parameter . If storeId has a value, `$match` should filter out based on `storeId`.

```
$match: {
       type: "abc",
      "_store._id":storeId?: //something like if else here 
    }
```

What should I add here ?

Comment: I'd just have if/else condition in my javascript to check if `storeId` is undefined, then I use the query without `_store._id` and if `storeId` has some value then use the query with `_store._id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this by creating an empty object to match against and then populate it conditionally:

```
var match = {};
if (storeId != undefined) match.storeId = storeId;
if (type != undefined) match.type = type;
//...
```

and then use that object in the aggregation pipeline:

```
 { $match: match }
```